# 4 MB .txt file in android application

Tags: android

I have a really big .txt file ( 4.2MB) that I have to access in my android application. It consists of words and their definitions in this format:

```
word - definition
word2 - definition2
```

Should I put this file in /assets folder or in res/raw? Or something third? Maybe I should put it on SD card because of its size?

And how should I get file contents in the code?
I have tried both assets and res/raw, but the file size always seems to be the problem or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: How is the file size a problem? Do you get any errors? What errors?

Comment: No errors, it just doesnt load anything when I use a bigger file. Everything is saved in sqlite database so I am having some problems debugging this error because I am not sure how to easily access contents of sqlite db on android emulator.

Comment: What happens when you put it in the assets folder (because that's where it should be)? Do you get errors? Do you get an empty file? Does the same code work for a smaller file?

Comment: I got some RAM errors because emulator doesn't have enough memory. So i decided to run it on my mobile phone, guess there weren't errors of that type but it loaded only a small part of lines(words and definitions) from the .txt file. App is similar to SearchableDictionary sample and it uses sqlite for data storage.

Answer (score 1):

A SQLLite database could be used for this.

An example of this can be found in the latest android SDK. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html

Comment: This is the ultimate resort. you can create a SQL database and bundle it with your app after running zipalign.

Comment: My application is based on this application! So indeed I am using sqlite database. The only difference is that I am using larger file than it is in sample. So I could reformulate the question: how to use 4MB definitions file with Searchable dictionary sample application?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in raw folder would be a better idea according to me.
since putting in the SDCard would make it available to user also, and the user might screw up your database.

Comment: Why do you think putting it in raw folder would be better than assets? I read somewhere that there is a limit for raw folder files which is 1MB. So only way to put it there would be to split file in 5 parts and read separetly, but it didnt work this way too.

Comment: I didn't come across anything like that. in fact, one of my team mate used data around 5 MB in Raw folder. Raw folder data isn't compressed or optimised at the time of build, so you get exactly what you put there.